# Issue with using nested case conditions in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, case

i have a scenario where in , i need to calculate an employeee salary using a package , which gives me salary remaining for permanent employee if there is some prepayment and then convert the calculated value to a currency specified by the employee using another package.

How i have been doing this is:

```
CASE
  WHEN ( ai.employee_type = 'PERMANENT' and ai.payment_status_flag='Y')
  THEN EMP_UTILS_PKG.get_pay_amount_remaining( ai.employee_id )
  ELSE ail.amount_remaining
END amount_remaining,
CASE
  WHEN ( ai.salary_currency_code = NVL(find_currency('EMP_COMMON_CURRENCY'),ai.EMP_CURRENCY_CODE))
  THEN CASE
             WHEN ( ai.employee_type = 'PERMANENT' and ai.payment_status_flag='Y')
                THEN EMP_UTILS_PKG.get_pay_amount_remaining( ai.employee_id )
             ELSE ail.amount_remaining
  END
  ELSE EMP_API.convert_closest_amount_sql( x_from_currency => ai.EMP_CURRENCY_CODE ,x_to_currency => find_currency('EMP_COMMON_CURRENCY') ,x_amount =>( CASE
             WHEN ( ai.employee_type = 'PERMANENT' and ai.payment_status_flag='Y')
                THEN EMP_UTILS_PKG.get_pay_amount_remaining( ai.employee_id )
             ELSE ail.amount_remaining
END) ,x_max_roll_days => -1)
END EMP_CONVERTED_AMOUNT_REMAINING,
```

I have repeated below condition 3 times in my query:

```
WHEN ( ai.employee_type = 'PERMANENT' and ai.payment_status_flag='Y')
   THEN EMP_UTILS_PKG.get_pay_amount_remaining( ai.employee_id )
   ELSE ail.amount_remaining
```

Is there a simpler approach for this, can we avoid repeating code like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline view in the `FROM` clause to simplify this. Use the joins properly in your live code.

```
SELECT amount_remaining
     , CASE
          WHEN ai.salary_currency_code = NVL(find_currency('EMP_COMMON_CURRENCY')
                                            ,ai.EMP_CURRENCY_CODE)
               THEN amount_remaining

          ELSE EMP_API.convert_closest_amount_sql(
                   x_from_currency => ai.EMP_CURRENCY_CODE
                  ,x_to_currency => find_currency('EMP_COMMON_CURRENCY')
                  ,x_amount => amount_remaining
                  ,x_max_roll_days => -1)
        END EMP_CONVERTED_AMOUNT_REMAINING,
FROM (SELECT CASE
               WHEN ai.employee_type = 'PERMANENT'
                AND ai.payment_status_flag='Y'
                    THEN EMP_UTILS_PKG.get_pay_amount_remaining( ai.employee_id )
               ELSE ail.amount_remaining
             END amount_remaining
        FROM table_name);
```

Comment: I have edited it to add the missing line, can you please tell me if there is a way to avoid the duplicate code as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

You already use the function `EMP_UTILS_PKG.get_pay_amount_remaining` so why not create a PL/SQL function that encapsulates the logic and just call that in your multiple places.